# Using CSS, Can I specify a background-image outside that object?

Tags: html, css, styles

I have an object like this:

```
<div class="myObject">My Object</div>
```

I want to display a image ***in front of*** that `<div>`'s box, I thought code like this will work:

```
.myObject {
    background-image: url(foo.png);
    background-position: 0px -20px;
}
```

But, unfortunately, this does not work.

How can I accomplish this goal using CSS?

**PS: What I want is just to display that image outside that tag's box, don't tell me to do like this:**

```
.myObject {
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-image: url(foo.png);
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't position a background image on an element outside the box.

To place an image to the left of an element, using pure CSS, the [`:before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/::before) pseudo-element can be used:

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2HEpn/

```
.myObject:before {
    content: " ";
    background-image: url("/favicon.ico");  /* a 16x16 image, for example */
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    display: inline-block;  /* pseudo-elements are inline by default */
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but in this case: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/2HEpn/2/) can I display that icon in front of that red space?

Comment: @UniMouS The element can be moved outside by playing with negative left margins: http://jsfiddle.net/2HEpn/3/. A parent-selector does not exist in CSS, so the container cannot be moved though

Answer (score 0):

you might need to place it relativly inside the object as i understand from u to the div

```
#img{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:-30px;
}
.myobject{
position:relative;
width:30px;
}
```